# decltype deducted result of in-class defined function

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, return-type-deduction

Why does

```
struct MyStruct {
   auto foo () { return 1; }
   auto bar () { return foo(); }
};
```

compile, but when using a trailing return type like so:

```
struct MyStruct {
   auto foo () { return 1; }
   auto bar () -> decltype(foo()) { return foo(); }
};
```

compilation fails with

> error: function 'foo' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined

Is this correct behavior on the implementations' part?

Comment: Yes. The member function bodies logically follow the class definition, even if defined inline.

Comment: Well, if you can use simple `auto` deduction on the return type of `foo`, why not use it for `bar` as well?

Comment: I do not see the point of `decltype`. Am I missing something? Are you looking for `auto& foo () { return i; }   auto bar () ->decltype(auto) { return foo(); }`?

Comment: @ZDF This problem occurred when writing compile-time reflection. Firstly, I've wrote compile-time string "whitch will be our foo" [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d8590eae31984a6) (We can't deduce type of string) Secondly, I've wrote compile-time reflection of class vars and methods (methods removed to simplify code) [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e03a1f0510bb0c3a) (We must deduce all result types, becouse all next states will depend on prev states) (our bar). I would like to put it all together, but will rewrite reflection outside of the class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first snippet, we can deduce the (effective) return type, because the definition is provided at that lexical point—and conversely will not work if [the definitions are lexically swapped](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/005c570eb047faac), which is in unison with [[dcl.spec.auto]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#10), since we must disallow cyclic deduction.

Concerning the second snippet, see [core issue 945](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#945), which effectively reopened [core issue 643](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#643) and deals with `this` being used in trailing return types, in which the class type is incomplete still. AFAICS, current wording  permits it in the same manner as in the first case (again given proper order of the definitions), but keep the open issue [1890](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1890) in mind; vendors defer implementation of questionable stuff until confirmed.

Comment: It seems to me that [CWG1890](http://wg21.link/cwg1890) is relevant to this issue.

Comment: @bogdan  I am slightly confused, because I feel that the code shouldn't be ill-formed in the first place, i.e. if anything the current wording is more prohibitive than it should be.

Comment: @bogdan CWG1890 is about types of data members. The question is about a function declaration. How is it relevant? Just curiosity, not a criticism.

Comment: @skypjack A member's declaration depends on the definition (not its existence, but its actual content) of another member. It is not clear whether that should be valid or not.

Comment: @Columbo I see. The example code from the issue made me think it was limited to data members. Sorry. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not clear from the standard wording how "the class is incomplete" and "the member function body is not available" interact. Is the class being complete a necessary condition for the member function bodies to become available? I don't think the standard says that anywhere. Clearly it's not a sufficient condition, since at the `}` of the class definition the class is complete even if no member function bodies have been provided yet. cc @skypjack

Comment: I understand implementations use a model where the member function definitions provided in the class definition behave as if provided immediately after the `}`, but I don't think that's specified anywhere in the standard. Do they behave as if they were defined in the same order as in the class definition (this is relevant to the handling of the first example in the question when the definitions are swapped)?

Comment: Also, note that `this->foo` in the trailing return type of `bar` would be fine if `foo` didn't have a deduced return type (per [\[expr.prim.this\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this#2)), even if `*this` is not yet complete at that point.

Comment: @bogdan Fair point. I was confused by CWG 643 being NAD, while covering the same issue. Will revise.

Comment: @bogdan Yeah, so CWG 643 was reopened (they should've put a note into it). See my edit.

Comment: Aha, so that's when they introduced that wording. Nice find, it's interesting to see the different affected sections in one place. For reference, here's [N3282](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3282.pdf). I think the odds are that CWG1890 will be resolved by making the code in the issue description ill-formed. I suppose that will make OP's code ill-formed too. All four current compilers reject it, so it may be a case of adjusting the theory to conform to practice.